# using CArray object in CArray

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i have a problem to use CArray object in CArray

```
// .h file
class ArrClass : public CArray<int, int>
{
public:
    int m_id;
    void Func1(){ m_id = 1;};
};

// .cpp file
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    ArrClass arr1;
    CArray<ArrClass, ArrClass> arr2;
    arr2.Add(arr1);     // error !!!! 
}
```

this error is:

```
error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
```

how do i resolve it? please help me!

Comment: `CArray<ArrClass, ArrClass&> arr2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CArray` requires its element type to be copyable - but it is not itself copyable. For that reason, you cannot have a `CArray` of `CArray`s.

Consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: thank you Tandetnik, 
if i define “copy constructor” and “assignment operator” functions for "ArrClass" class , the error resolved.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I should define “copy constructor” and “assignment operator” functions for "ArrClass" class .

```
class ArrClass : public CArray<int, int>
{
public:
    int m_id;

    ArrClass(){};
    ArrClass(const ArrClass& obj){m_id = obj.m_id;};    // copy constructor
    void Func1(){ m_id = 1;};
    ArrClass operator=(const ArrClass& obj) // assignment operator
    {
        m_id = obj.m_id;
        return *this;
    };
};
```

the error resolved, thank you all.

Comment: Note that your copy constructor and assignment operator only copy over `m_id` member - but not the actual contents of the `CArray`. The "copy" will always be empty (as in, `GetSize()` will return 0). Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

is this code ok?

```
ArrClass(const ArrClass& obj)   // copy constructor
    {
        Copy(obj);

        m_id = obj.m_id;
    };  

ArrClass operator=(const ArrClass& obj) // assignment operator
    {
        Copy(obj);

        m_id = obj.m_id;
        return *this;
    };
```